# Google maps V2 - Authorization failure, I can't display map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying display a map on my app but I can't display, I's impossible for me...

### My steps:

1. Install "Google play services" from SDKManager.

[image: dib1]

2. Add library from Project

**build.gradle**

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "prueba.mapas.alvaro.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Add Library to `AndroidManifest.xml` too.

**Manifest (part)**

```
 <application

......
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

......

 </application>
```

3. Get SHA1

[image: dib2]

4. Go to "https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect" ato get API Key.

[image: fdf]

- Package name on Android Studio

[image: dib4]

5. Modify `AndroidManifest.xml` with permissions.

   ```
   <permission
       android:name="prueba.mapas.alvaro.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="prueba.mapas.alvaro.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
   <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
        Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true"/>

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

       //api key
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaSyD1UolEb1tDMe6qB5BUF5orFzc3CDtvJYg"/>

   </application>
   ```
6. Create my Layout `map_activity.xml`
7. Create my principal class `MainActivity.class`

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
       {

   ```
       @Override

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

           MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                   .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       }
   }
   ```
8. Connect my Device and it's reports that error and on my device always appear White screen.

[image]

**NOTE: ALWAYS I CLEAR DATA FROM MY APP ON MY DEVICE, UNISTALL AND INSTALL AGAIN, NOT WORKS**

**UPDATE**

I have enable Google Maps V2 on console

[image: enn]

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Solved, I put on the Manifest the "Key for browser apps (with referers)" instead of the "Key for Android apps (with certificates)" from the Google API Console

Comment: you put the answer in below...not in the question itself

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked for me (Use the key for browser apps).

Comment: Glad to receive your comment @JehoshaphAkshay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Put on the Manifest the "Key for browser apps (with referers)" instead of the "Key for Android apps (with certificates)" from the Google API Console

Comment: There is no code, it is simply doing what it says. In the section of the value of the API put the value of "Key for browser apps (with referers)" that Google returns to you. Generate this key then Copy/Paste on your manifest file

Comment: No, you need to change your manifest and compile again, then you can upload the new apk on Store.

Comment: Can U explain more, what Must I change?
I do what U say, and it's worked correctly, but I not know what must I do when publish my app

Comment: When you do that, just upload a new apk version on the Store, it will works correctly too. But you need to upload a new update for your users.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code. Sounds like well. 
But  try this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/iqamah_map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Use `FragmentActivity`

```
 public class YourActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
        map =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.iqamah_map)).getMap();

    }
}
```

Update your **`build.gradle`**

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, it's better with FragmentActivity

Comment: Glad to receive your comment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Authorization failure):

**The simple solution:**

At first I only managed to solve it by getting rid of all API key restrictions. If you're okay with having an unrestricted key, this is probably going to work just fine.

**My solution:**

I still wanted to use some restrictions. I started to play with the restriction settings until I found the source of the error:

[API key restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwmAZ.png)

If you select **Application restrictions** -> **Android apps** you will get a setting called **Restrict usage to your Android apps**. Here you need to supply your application's **Package name** and the **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint**.

The problem in my case had to do with the **package name**: The problem occurred because I created the **Map Fragment** where I want to display the Map in a sub package. For the **API key** to work you have to supply a package that looks like this:

correct package name example: **com.example.application**

Because I created the fragment in a sub package it automatically added the sub package to the API key restriction:

incorrect package name example: **com.example.application.subpackage**